# How to combine the data from two CSV files in BASH?

Tags: ruby, perl, bash, csv, python-2.7

I have two CSV files which use `@` to divide each column. The first file (file1.csv) has two columns:

```
cat @ eats fish
spider @ eats insects
```

The second file (file2.csv) has four columns:

```
info @ cat @ info @ info
info @ spider @ info @ info
info @ rabbit @ info @ info
```

I need to add the information from the second column of the first file to a new column in the second file, in cases where the details of the first column of the first file and the second column of the second file match, e.g., the result of the above would make this:

```
info @ cat @ info @ info @ eats fish
info @ spider @ info @ info @ eats insects
info @ rabbit @ info @ info @
```

As seen above, as the first file contained no information about rabbits, a new empty column is added to the last row of the second file.

Here is what I know how to do so far:

`while read line` can be used to cycle through the rows in the second file, e.g.:

```
while read line
do
    (commands)
done < file2.csv
```

The data from particular columns can be accessed with `awk -F "@*" '{print $n}'`, where `n` is the column number.

```
while read line
do
    columntwo=$(echo $line | awk -F "@*" '{print $2})
    while read line
    do
        columnone=$(echo $line | awk -F "@*" '{print $1})
        if [ “$columnone” == “$columntwo” ]
        then
            (commands)
        fi
    done < file1.csv
done < file2.csv
```

My approach seems inefficient and I am not sure how to use add the data from the second column of `file1.csv1` to a new column in `file2.csv`.

- Items in column 1 of `file1.csv1` and column 2 of `file2.csv` are unique to those files. There are no duplicate entries within those files.
- The resulting file should have exactly 5 columns in every line, even if some columns are empty.
- The file contains a lot of characters from various languages in UTF-8.
- There is white space around `@`, but if this causes problems with the script, I can delete this.

How can the data from the first file be added to the data in the second file?

Comment: Matching rows are in the same order in both files?

Comment: Might it not be easier to write, say, a python script that reads the two files into data structures that can be searched and modified easily and intelligently, then writes the result to your new file?

Comment: why bash? you're already involving awk, so why not just use a real language?

Comment: The matching rows are not in the same order in both files. Some lines also might contain similar content, e.g. "@ tree @" and "@ tree frog @", but only lines with a complete match should be considered a match.

Comment: If BASH is not suited for this kind of task, I have added some other languages which I have installed on my system.

Comment: awk is certainly suited to this task. But sorry I can't help on this one. I'm heading out for the night. Good luck.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

And a nice, clean `awk` solution:

```
awk -F" *@ *" 'NR==FNR{lines[$2]=$0} NR!=FNR{if(lines[$1])lines[$1]=lines[$1] " @ " $2} END{for(line in lines)print lines[line]}' file2.csv file1.csv
```

A nice one-liner. Not a short one, but not the longest I've seen. Note that file2 and file1 are switched. Again, as a script with explanation:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

# Split fields on @ and the whitespace on either side.
BEGIN { FS = " *@ *" }

# First file
NR == FNR {
    #Store the line
    lines[$2] = $0
}

# Second file
NR != FNR {
    # If the appropriate animal was in the first file, append its eating habits.
    # If not, it's discarded; if you want something else, let me know.
    if(lines[$1]) lines[$1] = lines[$1] " @ " $2
}

# After both files have been processed
END {
    # Loop over all lines in the first file and print them, possibly updated with eating habits.
    # No guarantees on order.
    for(line in lines) print lines[line]
}
```

Call as `awk -f join.awk file2.csv file1.csv`, or make executable and `./join.awk file2.csv file1.csv`.

Answer (score 5):

[jowdder's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10038133/900873) is almost there, but incomplete because of the problems I mentioned in a comment there: there will be unwanted whitespace in the fields and the files aren't sorted, which they need to be.

```
join -t@ -11 -22 -o2.1,0,2.3,2.4,1.2 <(sed 's/ *@ */@/g' file1.csv | sort -t@) <(sed 's/ *@ */@/g' file2.csv | sort -t@ -k2) | sed 's/@/ @ /g' > output-file
```

This can also be written as a bash script, and I'll explain each step in it:

```
#!/bin/bash -e

# Remove whitespace around the `@`s, then sort using `@` to separate fields (-t@). 
# -k2 tells sort to use the second field.
sed 's/ *@ */@/g' file1.csv | sort -t@ >temp-left
sed 's/ *@ */@/g' file2.csv | sort -t@ -k2 >temp-right

# Join the files. -t@ means break fields at @, 
# -11 says use the first field in the first file,  -22 is the second field in the second file.
# -o... controls the output format, 2.1=second file, first field; 0 is the join field.
join -t@ -11 -22 -o2.1,0,2.3,2.4,1.2 temp-left temp-right > temp-joined

# Add whitespace back in around the @s so it looks better.
sed 's/@/ @ /g' temp-joined >output-file

# Clean up temporary files
rm temp-{left,right,joined}
```

Comment: When I try either script, it reports an error: `join: file 2 is not in sorted order`. What kind of order must it be in for this to work?

Comment: `sort`'s default order should be correct. Do the temporary files look properly sorted?  What version of `sort` and `join` do you have?

Comment: The resulting `temp-left` and `temp-right` files appear sorted differently, some items which appear earlier in `temp-left`, appear later in `temp-right`. Using `sort sort (GNU coreutils) 8.5` and `join (GNU coreutils) 8.5`.

Comment: My sort seems to be in the proper order, can you try to find and post a small subset of lines that don't sort properly?

Comment: Also, have you tried my `awk` solution below? It doesn't depend on the files being sorted.

Comment: I overlooked `awk` solution when I tested the answers. I will award the bounty to your answer when that option is available.

Answer (score 3):

This is what POSIX's [`join`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/000095399/utilities/join.html) utility is for.  After sorting `file1.csv` and `file2.csv` (sorting the latter on the second field), run something along the lines of:

```
join -2 2 -a 2 -t @ -e '' -o 2.1,0,2.3,2.4,1.2 file1.csv file2.csv
```

Comment: Almost. `-t @` splits strictly on the `@`, leaving whitespace on the left side of the second file but not the first. Also, they need to be sorted.

Answer (score 2):

This might work for you:

```
sed -e '1i\s/$/ @/' -e 's|^\([^@]*\)@\(.*\)|/^[^@]*@ \1/s/$/\2/|' file1.csv |
sed -f - file2.csv
info @ cat @ info @ info @ eats fish
info @ spider @ info @ info @ eats insects
info @ rabbit @ info @ info @
```

It might not be very fast on large volumes however!

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** After digging through the documentation for [`Text::CSV`](http://p3rl.org/Text%3a%3aCSV) (which is the underlying parser/writer engine) I found the `quote_space` option which prevents the existance of whitespace from triggering quotation of the the field. In your question you say that you can allow the removal of the whitespace around the `@` character, this method will do that for you in the process, but if that is acceptable then this answer should now meet all the criteria.

Here is a quick example using Perl and my [`Tie::Array:CSV`](http://p3rl.org/Tie%3a%3aArray%3a%3aCSV). This module allow you to treat a CSV file just as you would a native Perl 2D array.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::Array::CSV;
use List::Util 'first';

my %opts = (
  text_csv => { 
    sep_char => '@',
    allow_whitespace => 1,
    quote_space => 0,
  }, 
);

tie my @file1, 'Tie::Array::CSV', 'file1.csv', %opts;
tie my @file2, 'Tie::Array::CSV', 'file2.csv', %opts;

foreach my $line (@file2) {
  my $animal = $line->[1];
  my $eats = first { $_->[0] eq $animal } @file1;
  if ( $eats ) {
    push @$line, $eats->[1];
  } else {
    push @$line, '';
  }
}
```

Depending on how large file1.csv is, it might be better to parse that whole file into memory for more efficient searching.

Anyway here is the option for parsing in file1.csv first

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

use Tie::Array::CSV;

my %opts = (
  text_csv => { 
    sep_char => '@',
    allow_whitespace => 1,
    quote_space => 0,
  }, 
);

tie my @file1, 'Tie::Array::CSV', 'file1.csv', %opts;
tie my @file2, 'Tie::Array::CSV', 'file2.csv', %opts;

# parse in file1 so that it doesn't need to be searched each time
my %eats;
foreach my $line (@file1) {
  $eats{$line->[0]} = $line->[1];
}

foreach my $line (@file2) {
  my $animal = $line->[1];
  push @$line, $eats{$animal} || '';
}
```

Comment: The lengths of the files will vary, but usually `file1.csv` is about 5,000 words, `file2.csv` is about 100,000 lines.

Answer (score 1):

Also take a look at the DBD::CSV perl module. It will treat each file as a table and allow you to write an SQL join on them. http://metacpan.org/pod/DBD::CSV

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said why you have to do this in bash. It's much easier in a full-featured language like ruby, python, or perl.  Here's a short ruby program:

```rb
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

f1_map = Hash[ * IO.readlines('file1.csv').map {|l| l.chomp.split(/\s+@\s+/,2) }.flatten ]

STDIN.each_line do |l|
  cols = l.chomp.split /\s+@\s+/
  puts ( cols << f1_map[cols[1]] ).join(' @ ')
end
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a [solution based in a Ruby script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25085688/316700) that can be executed from console.

I'm sure you can make the necessary adaptations for your specifics, like the "@" as a field separator.