# Ruby how to merge two CSV files with slightly different headers

Tags: ruby, csv, merge

I have two CSV files with some common headers and others that only appear in one or in the other, for example:

```
# csv_1.csv
H1,H2,H3
V11,V22,V33
V14,V25,V35
```

```
# csv_2.csv
H1,H4
V1a,V4b
V1c,V4d
```

I would like to merge both and obtain a new CSV file that combines all the information for the previous CSV files. Injecting new columns when needed, and feeding the new cells with *null* values.

Result example:

```
H1,H2,H3,H4
V11,V22,V33,
V14,V25,V35,
V1a,,,V4b
V1c,,,V4d
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Challenge accepted :)

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require "csv"

module MergeCsv
  class << self
    def run(csv_paths)
      csv_files = csv_paths.map { |p| CSV.read(p, headers: true) }
      merge(csv_files)
    end

    private

    def merge(csv_files)
      headers    = csv_files.flat_map(&:headers).uniq.sort
      hash_array = csv_files.flat_map(&method(:csv_to_hash_array))

      CSV.generate do |merged_csv|
        merged_csv << headers

        hash_array.each do |row|
          merged_csv << row.values_at(*headers)
        end
      end
    end

    # Probably not the most performant way, but easy
    def csv_to_hash_array(csv)
      csv.to_a[1..-1].map { |row| csv.headers.zip(row).to_h }
    end
  end
end

if(ARGV.length == 0)
  puts "Use: ruby merge_csv.rb <file_path_csv_1> <file_path_csv_2>"
  exit 1
end

puts MergeCsv.run(ARGV)
```

Comment: It works :).. you are not covering the case one of the CSV files contents only the _headers row_.. or not _row_ at all as I do but I suppose is a very specific scenario.

Comment: Simplied first answer:

Comment: Not bad, let me steal your idea make mine accept *n* csvs, no only 2.

Answer (score 2):

*I have the answer, I just wanted to help people that is looking for the same solution*

```ruby
require "csv"

module MergeCsv
  def self.run(csv_1_path, csv_2_path)
    merge(File.read(csv_1_path), File.read(csv_2_path))
  end

  def self.merge(csv_1, csv_2)
    csv_1_table = CSV.parse(csv_1, :headers => true)
    csv_2_table = CSV.parse(csv_2, :headers => true)

    return csv_2_table.to_csv if csv_1_table.headers.empty?
    return csv_1_table.to_csv if csv_2_table.headers.empty?

    headers_in_1_not_in_2 = csv_1_table.headers - csv_2_table.headers
    headers_in_1_not_in_2.each do |header_in_1_not_in_2|
      csv_2_table[header_in_1_not_in_2] = nil
    end

    headers_in_2_not_in_1 = csv_2_table.headers - csv_1_table.headers
    headers_in_2_not_in_1.each do |header_in_2_not_in_1|
      csv_1_table[header_in_2_not_in_1] = nil
    end

    csv_2_table.each do |csv_2_row|
      csv_1_table << csv_1_table.headers.map { |csv_1_header| csv_2_row[csv_1_header] }
    end

    csv_1_table.to_csv
  end
end

if(ARGV.length != 2)
  puts "Use: ruby merge_csv.rb <file_path_csv_1> <file_path_csv_2>"
  exit 1
end

puts MergeCsv.run(ARGV[0], ARGV[1])
```

And execute it from the console this way:

```sh
$ ruby merge_csv.rb csv_1.csv csv_2.csv
```

Any other, maybe cleaner, solution is welcome.

Answer (score 2):

Simplied first answer:

How to use it:

```
    listPart_A = CSV.read(csv_path_A, headers:true)

    listPart_B = CSV.read(csv_path_B, headers:true)

    listPart_C = CSV.read(csv_path_C, headers:true)

    list = merge(listPart_A,listPart_B,listPart_C)
```

Function:

```
def merge(*csvs)
    headers = csvs.map {|csv| csv.headers }.flatten.compact.uniq.sort
    csvs.flat_map(&method(:csv_to_hash_array))
end

def csv_to_hash_array(csv)
    csv.to_a[1..-1].map do |row|
      Hash[csv.headers.zip(row)]
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something very similar
to merge n CSV files that the might share some of the columns but some may not
if you want to keep a structure and do it easily,
I think the best way is to convert to hash and then re-convert to CSV file
my solution:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
require "csv"

def join_multiple_csv(csv_path_array)
  return nil if csv_path_array.nil? or csv_path_array.empty?
  f = CSV.parse(File.read(csv_path_array[0]), :headers => true)
  f_h = {}
  f.headers.each {|header| f_h[header] = f[header]}
  n_rows = f.size
  csv_path_array.shift(1)
  csv_path_array.each do |csv_file|
    curr_csv = CSV.parse(File.read(csv_file), :headers => true)  
    curr_h = {}
    curr_csv.headers.each {|header| curr_h[header] = curr_csv[header]}
    new_headers = curr_csv.headers - f_h.keys
    exist_headers = curr_csv.headers - new_headers
    new_headers.each { |new_header|
      f_h[new_header] = Array.new(n_rows) + curr_csv[new_header]
    }
    exist_headers.each {|exist_header|
      f_h[exist_header] = f_h[exist_header] + curr_csv[exist_header]
    }
    n_rows = n_rows + curr_csv.size
  end
  csv_string = CSV.generate do |csv|
    csv << f_h.keys
    (0..n_rows-1).each do |i|
      row = []
      f_h.each_key do |header|
        row << f_h[header][i]
    end
    csv << row
  end  
    end
    return csv_string
end


if(ARGV.length < 2)
  puts "Use: ruby merge_csv.rb <file_path_csv_1> <file_path_csv_2> .. <file_path_csv_n>"
  exit 1
end

csv_str = join_multiple_csv(ARGV)
f = File.open("results.csv", "w")
f.write(csv_str)
puts "CSV merge is done"
```